# How to change text in the input bar

Tags: forms, input

I have this code for my form, it inherits the text color of the theme am using, I want give a different color to the text in the input text bar, I have the form below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
input{
    color: [some color];
}
```

Try doing it in css. Might want to add a class to the css/input to uniquely identify it and avoid global styles.

This can either go in a css stylesheet or a style tag on the page.

A stylesheet in generally recommended, but a style tag would go above the markup like this

```
<style>
input{
        color: [some color];
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Please can you show me how it would be added to the code? Just the global style. Thanks